# Trying to recall the title and author of this unusual baseball centered story from the 1970s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I heard a short story read I believe by Jim Freund on his radio show "Hour of the Wolf" on WBAI radio in New York in the 1970s about a baseball player who upends the game with radical and by normal standards seemingly *impossible* super-human and magical play that is still technically adherent to the rules.  The feats described are so extraordinary, that one is left to wonder if this player is actually a human, or perhaps something else. For example, he has a method of hitting the ball where he holds his bat pointed at the incoming ball like a pool cue stick, and not only connects with the ball head on, but advances the bat in a way that the ball rebounds with such extreme speed and force that instead of trying to catch it, players just get out of the way lest they be injured!  In the story, this particular batting method comes to be called "The Laser".  This player also employed a number of other strange though effective and entertaining methods of play.  Does anyone remember this story?  I'm trying to remember its title and author, and possibly the name of an anthology in which it might have exclusively appeared.  It is also possible that it only appeared in a magazine as featured fiction.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi Roger and welcome to the SFF stack exchange. Can you clarify what makes this story science fiction or fantasy? It seems to be just a story about baseball.

Comment: Hi John, I think the story falls in the fantasy category, as the techniques used by the player in the game, like the "laser" technique I detailed, and others in the story, are impossible by any conventional standards of physics, human accuracy, strength, and capacity, and I believe the story can therefore be classified as fantasy.  The story is not just about a good player or an extraordinary player, it's about an _impossible_  magical other-worldly player!

Comment: If it's on the fence (noting that Hour of the Wolf rarely broadcast stories that weren't at least slightly sci-fi/fantasy), then I think we're ok to leave it open. If it turns out not to be, we can always close it then.

Comment: Is it actually allowed in baseball to hit the ball as in billiard?

Comment: I did run across a story where the pitcher exercises a kind of mind control to get batters to not swing at his pitches, but I don't think that's the one you're looking for because I didn't see the "billiard shot" thing discussed.

Comment: Hi Deschele, I took a look at the 173 page Official Major League Baseball Rules last revised 2019 at MLB.com and specifically section 5.04 "Batting", and section 6.03 "Batter Illegal Action" and did not find that this fictional baseball player with his unique batting style would be in violation!  For conventional humans, the "Laser" batting style would be highly unsuccessful and therefore the player would be self-eliminating, however the fantasy batter of this very entertaining story seems to have superhuman capabilities.